# HTML5 / JS / Offline mode - request for page with query parameters

Tags: html, offline-caching

I have a page which is part of Cache manifest (/cache).

As soon as my application is offline mode, I can open that page (`http://app/cache`). But if I try to access it with query string, Chrome treat it as Non-Existing and return fallback page (`http://app/cache?url=1234` - does not work).

Does anyone know workaround for that?

Comment: OK, I read somewhere that it is not actually possible. As workarond I'm passing data throught localStorage. Works for me :)

Answer (score 6):

I would use # - has tag to pass parameters. Like this:

```
http://app/cache#url/1234
```

Browsers ignores the hashtag, but your page javascript can parse and act on it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be true that you will not be opening a page by tying the url on the browser. You will be clicking on a page to open the page. So on click call a Javascript function. Pass the querystring value to the function. save the querystring value to localstorage with a name.

When the page opens up read this value from localstorage on page load and get the value and use in your page.